# Argument list too long error for wkhtmltoimage

Tags: php, arguments, wkhtmltoimage

I want to capture the screen and store it to to the server. I have used the below command to achieve the screen capture in my php code.

```
$exec_command = "wkhtmltoimage --quality 10 --window-status 'wbcaptureready' --width 1200 --post 'estr' 
'JTNDVFZXQiUzRSUzQ3diJTIwc0lkJTNEJTIyd2I3NzYyNzVpeWFma3hya3Qy9UVldCJTNF' --post 'ispagehasdocument' '0' --height 1260 --enable-plugins --no-stop-slow-scripts https://example.org/page/capture/ '/data/screencapture/data/1234/1256/screenshots/screenshots/wbPage_^{4BEFBE59-EF14-4de4-9D08-3267BB76D8EA^}_0.png'";
$output = system($exec_command, $resCommand);
```

When I run the above code it works fine. But when I passed huge text of values to the parameter named `estr` it throws error code number 127(command can not found) when i echo the value of `$resCommand`. And also when I try to execute the command in the putty it throws error like below,

```
-bash: /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage: Argument list too long
```

Based on the above error I surfed in the internet and I got suggestion like I have to increase the `ARG_MAX` value. But the suggestions were not clear and vague. I could not located the argument and how to increase the value.

Kindly suggest me where and how to increase the `ARG_MAX` value or kindly suggest me if any other solution is available to fix this issue?.

My OS version: - `Linux version 2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c1bl.rdu2.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) )`

Thanks,
Ravichandran

Comment: Can you share such a value which causes error? If so does this value has any of the characters `$/\'"`

Comment: @TarunLalwani No it does not having $/\'" these characters. it is base64 encoded text.

Comment: Probably hitting this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720253/is-there-a-limit-on-the-length-of-command-passed-to-exec-in-php

Comment: @TarunLalwani I clearly mentioned the error `Argument list too long`. How can i fix this?. Is there any other way to fix this issue?.

Comment: Can you please confirm how much is the length, after which you get an error? as per me it should be `8192`

Comment: @TarunLalwani The argument length is nearly 170535. It may exceeds based on the user inupt text.

Comment: I am saying at what point do you get the error, can you confirm it is after 8192?

Comment: Can you please share the output of `system("getconf ARG_MAX", $resCommand);`? Also can you share an actual command I can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Any update on the answer I posted?

Comment: @RavichandranJothi It is always nice to get engaged in answers people are providing so that they get to know whether things worked for you or not. It will also help other people who might end up on this page later to find solutions. Any kind of feedback is always better than no feedback.

Comment: @KamalSoni Hey you are right. understood your concern. I will test it and reply soon. It is getting delayed because of some other priorities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to test it, but I believe the below  workaround should help you solve the issue. It is probably best to leave the ARG_MAX value untouched as it can have side effects.

```
//This value can't have any spaces and as your string is base64encoded it shouldn't be a problem in your case.
$estrVal = 'JTNDVFZXQiUzRSUzQ3diJTIwc0lkJTNEJTIyd2I3NzYyNzVpeWFma3hya3Qy9UVldCJTNF';
//You can also create a unique file name instead of estr.txt & may be delete it later if not needed.
$estrFile = './path/to/estr.txt'; 
file_put_contents($estrFile, $estrVal);

$exec_command = "wkhtmltoimage --quality 10 --window-status 'wbcaptureready' --width 1200 --post 'estr' \"$(< ./path/to/estr.txt)\"
 --post 'ispagehasdocument' '0' --height 1260 --enable-plugins --no-stop-slow-scripts https://example.org/page/capture/ '/data/screencapture/data/1234/1256/screenshots/screenshots/wbPage_^{4BEFBE59-EF14-4de4-9D08-3267BB76D8EA^}_0.png'";

$output = system($exec_command, $resCommand);
```

Comment: I think this idea should work. Need to check and confirm. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to run it like below

```php
$exec_command = "ulimit -s 65535 && wkhtmltoimage --quality 10 --window-status 'wbcaptureready' --width 1200 --post 'estr' 
'JTNDVFZXQiUzRSUzQ3diJTIwc0lkJTNEJTIyd2I3NzYyNzVpeWFma3hya3Qy9UVldCJTNF' --post 'ispagehasdocument' '0' --height 1260 --enable-plugins --no-stop-slow-scripts https://example.org/page/capture/ '/data/screencapture/data/1234/1256/screenshots/screenshots/wbPage_^{4BEFBE59-EF14-4de4-9D08-3267BB76D8EA^}_0.png'";
$output = system($exec_command, $resCommand);
```

This should probably increase argument list size for you

```php
php > $output = system("getconf ARG_MAX", $resCommand);
2097152
php > $output = system("ulimit -s 65535 && getconf ARG_MAX", $resCommand);
16776960
```