# Can't exceed 8175 chars on commands strings in exec, system and shell_exec PHP functions

Tags: php, windows, shell

I'm encountering an issue where I need to write lengthy commands in PHP and execute them. However, when the command exceeds a length of 8175 characters, it fails to execute. Interestingly, if I manually copy and paste the same command into a terminal, it runs without any problems. Here's a basic example to illustrate the issue:

```
$longCommand = "echo ".str_repeat("a",8171); // longCommand length = 8176 -> fails
exec($longCommand, $output);
print_r($output);
```

If you reduce the $longCommand string to 8175 characters, it successfully executes. Is there a character limit imposed on commands when they are executed from PHP, and if so, how can I increase or bypass this limit?

Comment: Do you get a specific error when it fails?

Comment: no, I only get an empty output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14720361/5947043 seems to be the only thing I can find related to this, just from a very brief search. But it suggests it's not just you. What is making the command so large? Are you writing a lot of commands? Or providing a lot of input data? I guess the obvious workaround is to put those things into separate files (either load them into the command via a file, or write a shell file (e.g. bash script if it's bash) and/or exec that. Then you're not directly passing the data through the PHP command.

Comment: Works just fine over here. Might be OS dependent. Which OS are you on?

Comment: @volkerschulz You're right, I just tested it on server and it works. I use wamp on Windows, tried on a different windows and I got the same issue.

Comment: @mondersky Just for reference: I tried MacOS Sonoma and Debian 10.2.1-6 and even 100.000 does not post a problem at all.

Comment: Found it in the docs and posted as an answer. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found out that this is an officially documented limitation with Windows:

> The maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 8191 characters.
> This limitation applies to:
> the command line
> individual environment variables that are inherited by other processes, such as the PATH variable
> all environment variable expansions
> If you use Command Prompt to run batch files, this limitation also applies to batch file processing.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation)

Comment: Indeed, I was just commenting exactly the same thing.